# Find in command substitution: Empty result inside while, result in command line

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-substitution

I have this bash script to find files recovered by PhotoRec (files I know are there, but because of their number I can't locate them one by one), but the find command doesn't return any results, if I run one by one the script lines, (except the while loop) every single one works... except find. I'm using SystemRescueCd, so I changed **zsh** to **bash**, but even so the strange behavior doesn't change.

Here is the bash script doesn't work as it should:

```
#!/bin/bash

findpath="/media/samsung/recup_dir.2/"
echo "FIND PATH: $findpath"

fileslistfile="/media/windows2/photorec-created-files.txt"
rm -rf "$fileslistfile"
touch "$fileslistfile"
echo "FILES LIST FILE: $fileslistfile"
echo "* * * * *"

while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "LINE: $line"
    #echo "$line" >> "$fileslistfile"

    uncreatedfile=$(basename "$line")
    echo "UNCREATED FILE: $uncreatedfile"

    # this command doesn't return any result
    createdfile=$(find "$findpath" -name "$uncreatedfile" -print)
    echo "CREATED FILE: $createdfile"

    if [ "$createdfile" != "" ]; then
        echo "$createdfile" >> "$fileslistfile"
    else
        echo "$line" >> "$fileslistfile"
    fi
done < "/root/photorec-uncreated-files.txt"

exit 1
```

Here is the sequence of commands executed in CLI, that works OK:

```
findpath="/media/samsung/recup_dir.1/";
echo "FIND PATH: $findpath";

line="/media/samsung/recup_dir.1/inode_733583/R Jota - Pantomima-kCcgjM55IqA.mp4";
echo "LINE: $line";

uncreatedfile=$(basename "$line");
echo "UNCREATED FILE: $uncreatedfile";

# this command returns a result
createdfile=$(find "$findpath" -name "$uncreatedfile" -print);
echo "CREATED FILE: $createdfile";

if [ "$createdfile" = "" ]; 
then echo "FILE UNCREATED $line"; 
else echo "FILE CREATED $createdfile"; 
fi;
```

I played around with **IFS** variable in the **while** loop to **IFS=$'\n'** and with the **-print** and **-print0** params in **find** (even dropping both), the result is always the same...

So. why the same command substitution behave differently? what is missing in the bash script?

Comment: Can you run script with debug mode? `PS4='debug>' bash -x script.sh` and see what is getting updated in the `createdfile` variable?

Comment: Or) Maybe you have a typo? In the first part, the path is set to `findpath="/media/samsung/recup_dir.2/"` and in the next as `dir.1` as `findpath="/media/samsung/recup_dir.1/"`?

Comment: the script is running in debug mode but doesn't display any useful information. Yes there is a typo: it should be recup_dir.1 instead recup_dir.2, probably happens a minute before to post it, the behavior is the same.

Comment: I gave a second look to the debugged commands and found out the cause: the source file photorec-uncreated-files.txt has all the lines like this: "Can't create file /media/samsung/recup_dir.1/inode_733583/R Jota - Pantomima-kCcgjM55IqA.mp4:" (with the sentence "Can't create ilfe " and a colon in the end of line, that's bad because $line is the variable used by $uncreatedfile which is used in the param -name of the find command, and that's why never work inside the bash script. Thanks for the advice @Inian !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source file **photorec-uncreated-files.txt** has all the lines like this:

> Can't create file /media/samsung/recup_dir.1/inode_733583/R Jota - Pantomima-kCcgjM55IqA.mp4:

with the sentence "Can't create ilfe " at the beggining and a colon at the end. (Usually I delete those both using ViM, but seems that I've been forgetting to do that)

That's bad because **$line** is the variable used by **$uncreatedfile** to get the basename of the full path, which returns nothing, which is used then as a value of the param -name of the **find** command, which obviously returns nothing too, and that's why **find** never returns any result inside a bash script.